# Tips for writing better answers

Tags: discussion, answers

I was writing an answer to a question the other day and after I had finished it I wished I had some feedback as to what could make the answer better.  How could I write it better.  What headings could I put in to make it easier to follow.   Would a different flow make it easier to follow.

I guess what I was looking for was a bit of critique on my answer layout rather than necessarilly the content itself.

Is there room for that kind of feedback here?  Is that even something that people would want to do, or is it just a far-fetched idea?  I guess my thought is that creating better answers/answerers (not just high voted answers although I guess that would be the effect) will help drive peoples buy in to the site in general?

Comment: I think comments and/or chatroom would be the perfect medium to discuss a specific answer, no?

Comment: @Mat'sMug CR Meta is a fine place to discuss how to write better answers. [Example](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/907/9357)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your answer contains code that you want reviewed, then post the core part of your answer as another question. [This has a precedent, and is welcome](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/35331/9357)...

If you want to go through more than just the code, then as I see it, you have three options:

- head on over to [the 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) and discuss your answer in an informal setting
- ask your question [here on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you want to get a formal 'is that a decent Code Review answer' discussion.
- [Programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) includes discussion about:

  - development methodologies and processes
  - quality assurance and testing

  as part of their on-topic scope. You could consider asking about code-review best practices there.

Going to The 2nd monitor is always a good idea, whether you want to discuss your answer, or the weather.

Comment: Hmm, I was wondering about that; so rather than discuss code-review best practice on meta, you would want that to happen on programmers ?

Comment: @konijn - honstly, no.... but it is on-topic there... and not here on our main site.

Comment: @rolfl  Cheers.  I hadn't thought about SE but might stay away from there.  Meta for 2nd Monitor seems the best bet