# To what extent should a recorded Excel macro be rewritten (removing .Select)?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm just feeling my way around here, having had a post recently moved over from another site together with its question. While I like the idea of a place to ask specifically for improvements to working code, I also see the potential for a lazy coder to 'code dump' something like a rat's nest of recorded MS Office VBA in the hopes of getting someone to clean it up.

What are the expectations of an answer to a situation like that? Are rewrites to one or two blocked sections that address different methods sufficient to meet site standards of a quality answer or should larger or even complete rewrites be provided?

My viewpoint is generally to help the user(s) help themselves, not do their work for them. If I rewrite something like this:

```
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B8").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-45
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=-1
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
     (etc., etc., etc. ...)
```

To something like,

```
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
      .Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
       (you can follow this method for all of the others)
    End With
```

Is this a satisfactory rewrite that meets site standards? Granted, if the recorded code also included something like a `.Sort` operation then that should be addressed as well if an improvement could be offered.

<sub>Hmmm... might need a tag specifically for Site Standards; especially during the weaning period.</sub>

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me, but *short answers are acceptable!* No answer can claim completeness anyways... There is no actual need to use code-blocks in an answer, since explanations and clear references are often sufficient.

Comment: On a personal note, welcome to Code Review! Feel free to drop by [chat] or the [CR VBA chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba).

Comment: @Vogel612 - I'll edit my answer for clarity when I work out some verbiage. In short, I was wondering about site standards when dealing with recorded macro 'code dumps' which can get very repetitious and to what extent an answer should address the code as a whole. Are isolated pockets dealing with methods sufficient or should the code dump be treated as a whole?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that would be a satisfactory answer. Answers are under no obligation to provide *any code at all*. A ***good*** CR would point out that Select & Activate should be avoided [insert obligatory link here]. A ***great*** one would show exactly how to do that, but again, there's no obligation to do so.

Here is an example. [I recently answered a question more abstractly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/82530/41243). I simply pointed out where there was room for improvement and how to go about it, but I didn't hold OP's hand and re-write his code for him. I could have, but I just don't have that kind of time anymore. Many reviewers here don't.

Here are some relevant Metas.

> - [Tips for writing better answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1799/tips-for-writing-better-answers)
> - [Short answers and code-only answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/short-answers-and-code-only-answers)
> - [Answering Guidelines (answer length)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/answering-guidelines-answer-length)
> - [Checklist or general directions on how to write a good CR-ish answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/checklist-or-general-directions-on-how-to-write-a-good-cr-ish-answer)
> - [What makes for a good answer?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1958/what-makes-for-a-good-answer)

Comment: Hi @RubberDuck - That seems perfectly reasonable. The more answers I see, the better I get at formulating my own 'flavour' for the site. I'm accepting this as the answer if for nothing else than the one-stop-shop of all those relevant links.

Comment: You're welcome! and I would completely agree. The best way to learn the culture is to immerse yourself in it.